# How to do an I2C Read in C?

Tags: c, sensors, i2c, microchip, pressure

I'm trying to get the pressure from a sensor using I2C but I'm not sure on the C code.
So far I have this:

```
I2C1_MasterRead(&PressureData, 2, I2C_ADDR_DS, &status);
```

Where Pressure data is an 8 bit unsigned integer, the data is 2 bytes long, the address of the sensor, followed by what I think is a stop bit.

Does anyone have experience and can help me out?

Comment: It is probably easiest to start with an example, maybe this one: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m843185.aspx

Comment: Far too broad to be answered. It all depends on the specific hardware, the schematic and so on.

Comment: `PressureData` should be 2 bytes long, because you try to read 2 bytes. If it is only one byte (u8) then second byte will be lost.